Application icon on dash still shows as default cog icon after opening it
When I pin my PyQt6 application to the dash, the designated PNG icon is displayed correctly. However, upon launching the application, a separate icon, which is a default cog icon, appears in the dash. This new icon does not associate with the original pinned icon as expected, but instead operates independently. I am seeking a solution to ensure that when the PyQt6 application is launched, it remains associated with the original pinned icon rather than generating a new one. Any ideas?
Screen snip of the icon opening as default cog.
Note, blue icon on dash is the correct icon set for my application.
